# How big would a mat multiply be for it to be more effecient to use th gpu

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl

So I've been messing around with OpenCL kernels and I'm trying to understand GPU acceleration a bit better and I'm curious to find out how one would find the point at which it would be more computationally efficient to use GPU acceleration in place of tradition CPU computing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one-fits-all sharp threshold to when GPU parallelization is better as it depends on the hardware. The data transfer from CPU to GPU and back causes latency in the range of milliseconds and needs large amounts of data to run efficiently at full PCIe bandwidth. However since compute time for matrix multiplication scales with N^2, the performance benefits of the GPU will quickly overcome the additional latency. As a rule of thumb:

3x3 matrix -> use CPU

10x10 -> probably CPU is faster

100x100 -> probably GPU is faster

1000x1000 -> definitely GPU

1000000x1000000 -> use GPU, with CPU it would probably take days

There is also cases where it makes sense to do a 3x3 matrix on the GPU: if you have millions of parallel 3x3 matrix multiplications to compute. In this case, you would not parallelize over the matrix elements, but do one 3x3 multiplication sequentially per GPU thread.

As a final remark, on the GPU you should use the cache tiling optimization for large matrix multiplications. This makes it like 10x faster by loading chunks of the matrices in local memory (L2 cache), so it does not have to access the matrix elements multiple times from global memory (VRAM).